# Prime numbers in given range Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I tried to make a program that follows this line (Example how it should work);
User inputs:

```
Give lower limit: 1
Give upper limit: 10
```

Program should print from 1-10:

```
1 is not a valid start number.
2 is a prime number.
3 is a prime number.
4 is not a prime number, because 2 * 2 = 4
5 is a prime number.
...
10 is not a prime number, because 2 * 5 = 10
```

After checking the given range, it should print:

```
10 numbers was examined, 4 of which were prime numbers
The last found prime number is 7
```

I have tried to work around this for so long, I got too frustrated and lost it all. If someone has the solution for this, I'd love to see it and analyze it while also learning from it.

Appreciate it, this would be a massive help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lower = int(input("Give lower limit: "))               # Get lower bound, must be an int
upper = int(input("Give upper limit: "))               # Get upper bound, must be an int
print()                                                # Print an empty line
primes = []                                            # An array to store the primes in
for i in range(lower, upper+1):                        # Go through the range
    if i == 1:
        print("1 is not a valid start number")
    else:
        primeFlag = True                               # Will only remain as true if the number is prime
        for div in range(2, i):                        # Go from 2 to the current number
            if i % div == 0:
                primeFlag = False                      # If this happens, it isnt prime
        if(primeFlag):                                 # If it is a prime
            primes.append(i)                           # Add to primes array
            print(i," is a prime number")
        else:
            print(i," is not a valid prime")

print((upper-lower+1), " numbers were examined, ", len(primes), " were prime numbers")
print("The last found prime number is ", primes[-1:])
```

Will produce:

```
Give lower limit: 1
Give upper limit: 10

1 is not a valid start number
2  is a prime number
3  is a prime number
4  is not a valid prime
5  is a prime number
6  is not a valid prime
7  is a prime number
8  is not a valid prime
9  is not a valid prime
10  is not a valid prime
10  numbers were examined,  4  were prime numbers
The last found prime number is  [7]
```

I hope this is helpful, its gets you almost to the output you want, please take the time to understand and learn from this.

Comment: Is it too hard to do for example: 6  is not a valid prime, **because 2*3=6**?
I tried to add it my self to your code that it detects the needed numbers automatically, but I couldn't manage it.

Thanks for the code tho! Now I understand what I did wrong :)

Comment: Your welcome, please mark this as the answer to thanks me for my time!

Answer (score 0):

I first created a list of range `low and high`.  From there eliminated the `1` using `is not a valid start` then I made a simple check list that runs `i % n` for where `n` is values in range `2, i`. Now if `all(check)` that means all results returned non-zero so the number is prime.  If not I declared the number not prime, then using `enumerate, start = 2` if the `item` from `check is`0`,`not item`will return`True`and you can use the`idx`of that`0` value to explain why it is not a prime.

```
low = 1
high = 10

l = [*range(low, high + 1)]

for i in l: 
    if i == 1: 
        print('{} is not a valid start number'.format(i)) 
        continue 

    check = [i % n for n in [*range(2, i)]] 

    if all(check): 
        print('{} is a prime number'.format(i)) 

    else:
        print('{} is not a valid prime number'.format(i))
        for idx, item in enumerate(check, start = 2):
            if not item:
                print('\t{} * {} = {} '.format(idx, int(i/idx), i))
```

> ```
> 1 is not a valid start number
> 2 is a prime number
> 3 is a prime number
> 4 is not a valid prime number
>   2 * 2 = 4 
> 5 is a prime number
> 6 is not a valid prime number
>   2 * 3 = 6 
>   3 * 2 = 6 
> 7 is a prime number
> 8 is not a valid prime number
>   2 * 4 = 8 
>   4 * 2 = 8 
> 9 is not a valid prime number
>   3 * 3 = 9 
> 10 is not a valid prime number
>   2 * 5 = 10 
>   5 * 2 = 10
> ```

Comment: In what part does the code print all the possible multiplies? How can I edit it, if I want it to show max of two different ways (when you go up with the numbers), or only way way?
Thanks for the code BTW! I like the way you made it.

Comment: ` else:
        print('{} is not a valid prime number'.format(i))
        for idx, item in enumerate(check, start = 2):
            if not item:
                print('\t{} * {} = {} '.format(idx, int(i/idx), i))`  @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel last loop in the else statement loops through the check list enumerated starting at 2, then `if not item` tells that the value is 0 meaning its even division so we can take the `idx` of the item and print `idx * number/idx = number`

Comment: I mean, now it prints (for example): 8 is not a valid prime number
 2 * 4 = 8 
 4 * 2 = 8

How can I edit it, to make it output only 2 * 4 = 8 (not the 4 * 2 = 8)

Comment: I got it all now. Thanks !